# A button to attend a public event with PHP or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, events

I want to have a button (an image) and when a user clicks it automaticaly attend my public event, is that possible?
And I want to do it using PHP or/and javascript

Thanks

Comment: what does the question have to do with facebook?

Comment: Do you mean to set their Facebook event's status to "Attending"? From where? A Facebook app page or an external page? We need more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You'll need to have the [rsvp_event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) extended permission for the user.
And you can use both php and/or javasctipt to perform this action.

Taken from [Event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) - A connection in the faecbook graph api...

To mark an event as "attending" you make call to this url :
`https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/attending`

Comment: The rsvp_event extended permission is necesary even if the event is public? I've made some test in my tab and the URL you mention gave me all the people that actually attend that event

Comment: yes.. it is still necessary - the permission is for **updating the users rsvp**.  If the event itself is defined as public then you'll still be able to retrieve the list of users that are attending or declined and/or information about the event itself..